# Nokogiri get xpath from Nokogiri::XML::Element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

How to get xpath for `rc` an element returned by search

```
f=File.open('/media/cc.xml')
doc = Nokogiri::XML f

rc = doc.search('realmCode')
[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x15a4d714 name="realmCode" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x15a4dafc href="urn:hl7-org:v3"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x15a4d5c0 name="code" value="US">]>]
```

Is there a way to extract xpath from `rc` ?

updated with xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/ccda.xsl"?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc" xmlns:vocdo="urn:hl7-org:v3/voc" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mif="urn:hl7-org:v3/mif">
  <realmCode code="US"/>
  <typeId root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3" extension="POCD_HD000040"/>
  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.1"/>
  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.2"/>
  <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.19.5.99999.1" extension="Test CCDA"/>
  <code codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC" code="34133-9" displayName="Summarization of Episode Note"/>
  <title>Continuity of Care Document (C-CDA)</title>
  <effectiveTime value="20130809043133+0000"/>
  <confidentialityCode codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.25" codeSystemName="HL7 Confidentiality" code="N" displayName="Normal"/>
  <languageCode code="en-US"/>
  <recordTarget>
    <patientRole>
      <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.4.6" extension="1"/>
      <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.4.1" extension="123-101-5230"/>
      <addr use="HP">
        <streetAddressLine>1357 Amber Drive</streetAddressLine>
        <city nullFlavor="UNK"/>
        <state nullFlavor="UNK"/>
        <postalCode>97006</postalCode>
        <country nullFlavor="UNK"/>
      </addr>
      <telecom value="3545345" use="HP"/>
      <patient>
        <name use="L">
          <given qualifier="BR">test</given>
          <family qualifier="CL">overall</family>
          <prefix qualifier="IN">Mr</prefix>
        </name>
        <administrativeGenderCode codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1" codeSystemName="HL7 AdministrativeGender" code="M" displayName="Male"/>
        <birthTime value="19770429"/>
        <raceCode codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.238" codeSystemName="Race and Ethnicity - CDC" code="2028-9" displayName="Asian"/>
        <ethnicGroupCode codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.238" codeSystemName="Race and Ethnicity - CDC" code="2135-2" displayName="Hispanic or Latino"/>
        <languageCommunication>
          <languageCode code="eng"/>
          <preferenceInd value="true"/>
        </languageCommunication>
      </patient>
    </patientRole>
  </recordTarget>
</ClinicalDocument>
```

Comment: Could you show us some of the relevant XML so that we could build a solution and test it to see it work before we recommend something incorrectly?

Comment: can you provide more specific information about the attributes of the rc i assume? My bet is you need to keep digging down

Comment: @RyanBigg updated with xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rc is not *an* element-it's an *array* of matching elements:

```
results = rc.map do |node|
  Nokogiri::CSS.xpath_for node.css_path
end

p results
```

Or, if you know there is only one matching element:

```
xpath = Nokogiri::CSS.xpath_for rc[0].css_path
```

Note that xpath_for returns an array, so you will need to extract the first element of the array:

```
xpath.first
```

Comment: Please check the question its not CSS/css_path its about XML and xpath

Comment: @shiva, you don't understand the code.  You asked for an xpath, the code provides an xpath.  If in fact, you don't want an xpath for a given XML node, then change your question.